# Sources/replacements for idled?

Tags: unix, timeout

In the good old days there used to be a Unix program called "idled" that would log out idle users after warning them. It was really configurable and generally did the right thing.

Unfortunately it's no longer maintained and the [original source](http://www.darkwing.net/idled/) no longer exists.

Before I pull it out of old RPMs or openbsd ports, does anyone know if idled's been maintained elsewhere, or if there's some alternative I should be looking at instead?

Comment: Ugh, sorry to hear that.  Idled rocked!

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to set TMOUT in bash for your users (in /etc/profile or something).  Yes, they can work around it, but I'm sure they can work around anything.

Comment: Thanks! I knew about TMOUT, actually, but my main concern is that they can work around it without even trying, by leaving a program open. I need to prevent them from accidentally or intentionally leaving themselves logged into MySQL, or running top, or leaving an editor open, to meet one of the requirements of PCI compliance.

Comment: Good luck telling the difference between, say, a user with MySQL open, and a screen session with the same :)

Comment: http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/system/admin/idle/!INDEX.html looks like it's it... old though.

If this is a PCI requirement, someone has to have a maintained way to do this, right?

Answer (score 1):

It still exists, although these days it's called doinkd

https://sourceforge.net/projects/idled/